# How to get node behind a proxy?

Tags: node.js, npm, proxy, config

I have tried the standard commands

```
npm config set https-proxy http://aaa.ccc.com:3128
npm config set proxy http://aaa.ccc.com:3128
```

Still this line of code:

```
const request = require('request');

request({
    url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=av%2068%20av%20esperanza%20bogota',
    json: true // the response would be a json object ready to read
}, (error, response, body) => {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(body);
});
```

keeps saying

> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 216.58.222.202:443

It is a simple test to get a JSON for geolocation and stuff. Maybe --global option or some other stuff?
Also, when I set this proxy the standard way, I'm able to install packages, so it makes think there's some other "cable" I'm not getting right.

With Git, it worked correctly:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxyUsername:proxyPassword@aaa.ccc.com:port
```

But with node it won't.

What am I mising here?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have api key for google maps?

Comment: Inside environment variables, I have three variables for Google, the first one says google_api_key and is set to "no". I don't know how did it get set. On the other hand, the timeout exception really throws me off.

Comment: I'm trying mapquest now, Google changed its policies regarding api keys. Now, for the timeout issue, I bet it has something to do with the firewall.